# Make Ctrl+enter = submit

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, editor

I got used to being able to submit forms using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination. Could it be made that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> submits the form after typing in an answer (and question, if title and tags are set)?