# Cannot use Ctrl + Enter in the sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, form-submit

Whenever I try to edit and submit the answer, the Ctrl + Enter throws this message on the console. Can this be fixed?

[image: console error]

Checked in Stack Overflow. It was working till this morning. It's not a cache problem or duplicate of [Make Ctrl+enter = submit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268877/make-ctrlenter-submit).

Comment: Same cause as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319505/tag-edits-result-in-a-success-screen-instead-of-the-updated-post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out removing the line of code that defines submitButton breaks code that uses submitButton. Sorry for the trouble; this should now be fixed.

Comment: Thanks! `:)` Lemme check. Works fine now... `:)` Good that I didn't even clear cache, but it works. Nice way of caching and expiring assets. `:D`